# libfov problems in C++ game

Tags: c++, allegro

I've been making a game in which I want to use some FOV lighting. I'm trying out libfov and it seems perfect, I had some trouble getting it to compile which I figured out on my own, but when I try to run the compiled executable I get this in the terminal:

error while loading shared libraries: libfov.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

compiling with this: g++ overlord.cpp -lalleg -lnoise -lfov -o "Zombie Overlord"

I'm really confused... I've checked for a 'libfov.so.1' and it exists in /usr/lib. Is there something wrong with my install of libfov or something?

Comment: `g++ overlord.cpp -L/usr/lib -lalleg -lnoise -lfov -o "Zombie Overlord"`

Comment: I figured it out.
I needed to add '/usr/lib' to the '/etc/ld.so.conf' file and run 'sudo ldconfig'.
Lots of obscure fun.
Now to fix a segmentation fault.